# RabbitMQ flooded by new connections

Tags: java, android, rabbitmq, connection

i'm using java api client with Automatic Recovery but every time it loses the connection, when it reconnects it creates a new connection on a different port, flooding my RabbitMQ with multiple connections.The environment I am working on loses the connection frequently.

Is it possibile use the same connection when it tries to reconnect?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want is a `connection pool` to setup connection with RabbitMQ. Since you are using java-client, you may what to try **CachingConnectionFactory** that support channel caching(by default) as well as connection caching(extra setup required). You can check it here: [CachingConnectionFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/connection/CachingConnectionFactory.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also delete idle connection via the help of [heartbeat](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html)

Enable it in your java client

```
ConnectionFactory cf = new ConnectionFactory();
cf.setRequestedHeartbeat(60);
```

It can also be hardcoded in server's config

Or you may refer refer [Connection AutoRecovering](https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/current-javadoc/com/rabbitmq/client/impl/recovery/AutorecoveringConnection.html)

Comment: I used Lyra with heartbeat